# Having trouble converting some C# code to F# when having to do counts

Tags: f#

I have the following C# code:

(no need to understand the details of it, it's just to illustrate the question)

```
            long VolumeBeforePrice = 0;
            long Volume = 0;
            var ContractsCount = 0.0;

            var VolumeRequested = Candle.ConvertVolumes(MinVolume);

            // go through all entries
            foreach (var B in Entries)
            {
                // can we add the whole block?
                if (Volume + B.VolumeUSD <= VolumeRequested)
                {
                    // yes, add the block and calculate the number of contracts
                    Volume += B.VolumeUSD;
                    ContractsCount += B.VolumeUSD / B.PriceUSD;
                }
                else
                {
                    // no, we need to do a partial count
                    var Difference = VolumeRequested - Volume;
                    ContractsCount += Difference / B.PriceUSD;
                    Volume = VolumeRequested;   // we reached the max
                }

                VolumeBeforePrice += B.VolumeUSD;

                if (Volume >= VolumeRequested) break;
            }
```

it goes through entries of a trading order book and calculates the number of contracts available for a specific usd amount.

the logic is quite simple: for each entry there is a block of contracts at a given price, so it either adds the whole block, or it will add a partial block if it doesn't fit within the request.

I am trying to move this to F# and I am encountering some problems since I'm new to the language:

this is a partial implementation:

```
    let mutable volume = 0L
    let mutable volumeBeforePrice = 0L
    let mutable contractsCount = 0.0

    entries |> List.iter (fun e ->
        if volume + e.VolumeUSD <= volumeRequested then
            volume <- volume + e.VolumeUSD;
            contractsCount <- contractsCount + float(e.VolumeUSD) / e.PriceUSD
        else
            let difference = volumeToTrade - volume
            contractsCount <- contractsCount + difference / B.PriceUSD
            volume = volumeRequested // this is supposed to trigger an exit on the test below, in C#
    )
```

And I stopped there because it doesn't look like a very F# way to do this :)

So, my question is: how can I structure the List.iter so that:

```
- I can use counters from one iteration to the next? like sums and average passed to the next iteration
- I can exit the loop when I reached a specific condition and skip the last elements?
```

Comment: You can exit a loop early by raising an exception. But you should really consider a functional approach using recursion instead of trying to imitate an imperative approach in a language that isn't particularly suited for that style.

Comment: @glennsl, yes, I agree; that's why I asked the question because being all new to it I would be curious to see how this type of code gets broken down

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd avoid using `mutable` and use a pure function. For example, you could define a record for your result, e.g `Totals` (you may have a more meaningful name):

```ml
type Totals =
    { VolumeBeforePrice : int64
      Volume : int64
      ContractsCount : float }
```

And then you can create a function that takes the current totals and an entry as input, and returns a new totals as its result. I've annotated the function below with types for clarity, but these could be removed as they'd be inferred:

```ml
let addEntry (volumeRequested:int64) (totals:Totals) (entry:Entry) : Totals =
    if totals.Volume >= volumeRequested then
        totals
    elif totals.Volume + entry.VolumeUSD <= volumeRequested then
        { Volume = totals.Volume + entry.VolumeUSD
          ContractsCount = totals.ContractsCount + float entry.VolumeUSD / entry.PriceUSD
          VolumeBeforePrice = totals.VolumeBeforePrice + entry.VolumeUSD }
    else
        let diff = volumeRequested - totals.Volume
        { Volume = volumeRequested
          ContractsCount = totals.ContractsCount + float diff / entry.PriceUSD
          VolumeBeforePrice = totals.VolumeBeforePrice + entry.VolumeUSD }
```

Now you can iterate the list passing in the last total each time. Fortunately, there's a built in function [`List.fold`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.fold%5B%27t%2C%27state%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) that does this. You can read more about folds on [F# for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recursive-types-and-folds-2b/).

```ml
let volumeRequested = Candle.ConvertVolumes(minVolume)

let zero =
    { VolumeBeforePrice = 0L
      Volume = 0L
      ContractsCount = 0. }

let result = entries |> List.fold (addEntry volumeRequested) zero
```

Note that this will give you the correct result, but it does always iterate all entries. Whether this is acceptable likely depends on the size of the `entries` list. If you want to avoid this, you'd need to use recursion. Something like this:

```ml
let rec calculateTotals (volumeRequested:int64) (totals:Totals) (entries:Entry list) : Totals =
    if totals.Volume >= volumeRequested then
        totals
    else
        match entries with
        | [] -> totals
        | entry::remaining ->
            let newTotals =
                if totals.Volume + entry.VolumeUSD <= volumeRequested then
                    { Volume = totals.Volume + entry.VolumeUSD
                      ContractsCount = totals.ContractsCount + float entry.VolumeUSD / entry.PriceUSD
                      VolumeBeforePrice = totals.VolumeBeforePrice + entry.VolumeUSD }
                else
                    let diff = volumeRequested - totals.Volume
                    { Volume = volumeRequested
                      ContractsCount = totals.ContractsCount + float diff / entry.PriceUSD
                      VolumeBeforePrice = totals.VolumeBeforePrice + entry.VolumeUSD }
            calculateTotals volumeRequested newTotals remaining

let result = calculateTotals volumeRequested zero entries
```

Comment: Tail-recursion like `let rec calculateTotals`  above is the idiom in F# for how to do loops you need break out of. Tail-recursion also allows you to avoid mutability required by "normal" loops. Thank to TCO in F# tall recursion is fast and doesn't use stack-space. In short; I +1 this answer.

Comment: thanks a lot, I was specifically looking at how this type of C# code has to be rewritten in F# so I can understand the flow. this is very helpful!